# CIMv2 - Win32_Printer shared

Tags: php, winapi, wmi, wmic

I'm using 'cimv2' and when I try to show my shared printers from a specific PC, I cannot. My printers are shared in a Print Server, but it shows just my Local Printers.

My connection code is:

```
$WbemLocator = new COM ("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
$WbemServices = $WbemLocator->ConnectServer($pc, '\root\cimv2', 'domain\administrator', '******');
$WbemServices->Security_->ImpersonationLevel = 3;
```

My Select:

```
$printer = $WbemServices->ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer");
```

My Foreach:

```
<?php                       
foreach ( $printer as $res_printer ) {
echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>";
echo "<tbody>"; 
echo "<tr><td> Name</td><td>" . $res_printer->Name . "</td></tr>"; 
echo "<tr><td> Share Name</td><td>" . $res_printer->Sharename . "</td></tr>"; 
echo "</tbody>"; 
echo "</table>"; 
} ?>
```

What may I doing wrong or it cannot show 'cause it's a printer shared in another server?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I was reading at some foruns that it happens because the printers aren't installed locally, and the wmic can't shows printers installed at Print Server. Is it true? Thks.